# Longest sub array in rotating array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, rotation, subsequence

Is there any way to find the longest subarray of 1's in log(n) time?

example:

1. `110011111000` - then the output is 5 (from pos 5 to 10)
2. `1110011101` - the output here is 3 but after rotation 1 the array becomes `111100111` and the output is now 4.
3. `001111` - the output here is 4 from pos 3 to 6 but after rotation it becomes 3 from pos 4 to 6

Note: I found the longest subarray length in O(n) before rotation. How can I improve the solution after rotation if I have the past results?

Comment: Finding the longest subarray of 1 before any rotation is O(n). You can improve the check **after** rotation to O(1) if you have the previous results

Comment: @DavidWinder can you put up the algorithm please..... thats exactly what i want to do

Comment: Out for lunch - will post detailed answer later

Comment: how many time you will rotate the array?

Comment: @nightfury1204 no. of roations = length of array

Comment: @DavidWinder Please do it asap....  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow those steps:

1. find the longest subarray of 1 (in O(n)). During that loop find the first and last instance of 0.
2. Start rotating and update those parameters.
3. If the last index is 0 search for the previous 1 to keep updated the parameters (at complexity this will not go over O(n) total.

I will assume you know how to get max subarray index and count in O(n). In addition to that, you will need to find the second largest subarray (can be done in the same loop).

Let extract 2 more params - first and last zeros (Simple code - I can attach it if you need )

When you rotate the array there are 3 option:

1. Nothing change
2. Bigger subarray created
3. Current biggest subarray breaks

In the first and second cases - you only need to update the params - O(1) - you can know this is the case according your params. In the third, you will need to use the second longest subarray you find (notice that only 1 subarray can be break at a time)

For example, consider you have array: `1110011101` (as your example) and you have `max = 3` and `maxIndex = 5`. After running the `getZeroIndexs` function you also know that `firstZeroIndex = 3` and `lastZeroIndex = 8`.

How our var will look like after rotate?

```
max = 3
maxIndex = 6
firstZeroIndex = 4 // this will increase as long as the lastZeroIndex different then the array size
lastZeroIndex = 9 //this will go up till array.size - when it those you need to loop again till you find last
```

In this case, the first index move to 4 whats make him bigger then max -> `max = 4` and  `maxIndex = 0`.

Now your array is : `1111001110` so `lastZeroIndex = 9` as the array size so next rotation will yield:

```
max = 4
maxIndex = 1
firstZeroIndex = 0 
lastZeroIndex = ? // here you need to loop from the end of your array till you get 0 -> O(k) in total complexity, all the run together will be O(n)
```

Hope it clear, if not feel free to ask!

Comment: That really helped ......... i might ask for sudo code if required...... Thanks alot Sir

Comment: `In the third, you will need to use the second longest subarray you find (notice that only 1 subarray can be break at a time)` How can you keep track of second longest subarray in O(1), since in rotate operation break subarray. consider for this `011101101` after 6th rotation.

Comment: @nightfury1204 You only need to keep the second array index -> increase it every iteration and move to 0 when at the end - > notice that when it breaks that mean the longest subarray is **not** broke (only one can be broken at each step) so you can just return the biggest - in case the biggest broke you can return the second

Answer (score 0):

No, because you have to know every letter value to count 1s, which is O(n) at least.